# How to find: $g(n)= \sum_{d|n}\frac{\phi(d)}d=?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, multiplicative-function

How to find: $$f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} d \phi(d)=? $$,

$$ g(n)= \sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\phi(d)}d=?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(n)$ is a multiplicative function (that is, $f(uv) = f(u) f(v)$ for $\gcd(u,v) = 1$), so it is enough to compute it for the powers of a prime $p$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
f(p^{m}) &= \sum_{k=0}^{m} p^{k} \varphi(p^{k})
\\&=
1 + \sum_{k=1}^{m} p^{k} (p-1) p^{k-1}
\\&=
1 + (p-1) p \sum_{k=1}^{m} p^{2k-2}
\\&=
1 + p \frac{p^{2m} - 1}{p+1}.
\end{align}
$$

$g(n)$ is also multiplicative, and here a simpler calculation yields
$$
g(p^{m}) = 1 + m \frac{p-1}{p}.
$$