# Computing $f,g$ such that $f(n)=\sum_{d|n}d\varphi(d)$ and $g(n)=\sum_{d|n}\frac{\varphi(d)}{d}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, totient-function

Let that $n$ be a natural number and $\varphi(n)$ be the Euler totient function. Is there any formula or estimation for computing functions $f,g$ such that:
$$
f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d\varphi(d)
$$
and
$$
g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\varphi(d)}{d}
$$
For $n=p$ as the prime number it is clear that $f(p)=p^2-p+1$ and $g(p)=\frac{2p-1}{p}$.

Comment: Can you compute $f,g$ for prime powers?  Are $f,g$ arithmetic?

Comment: $h(n)=ng(n)$ is a [Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution): $h = \phi * \operatorname{Id}$. So is $f(n)/n$.

Comment: Yes, you can find this on this site. For example, $f(n)$ equals the sum of the orders of all elements of a cyclic group $C_n$ - see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685327/the-sum-of-the-orders-of-all-elements-of-a-group-g). The minimum and maximum has been studied, and references are given.

Comment: A corresponding post on [mathoverflow.se]: [Is there any way to estimate this functions:$f(n)=\sum_{d|n}d\varphi(d)$ and $g(n)=\sum_{d|n}\frac{\varphi(d)}{d}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462560)

Comment: Another post about the same function - but the one does not ask about asymptotics: [How to find: $g(n)= \sum_{d|n}\frac{\phi(d)}d=?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/341477)